# Google Drive API - Update Spreadsheet data

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to send data from my web application to a google drive spreadsheet, so it will be easier for other people see data. So I have one spreadsheet and I want to add lines to it whenever there is new data.

My question is, is there an option to just add a line to a spreadsheet?

If not, then I suppose the only way to accomplish this is by getting the file, adding the line, and than uploading again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Google Drive API is meant for generic file / folder interactions. For directly modifying Google Spreadsheet data, the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) would be the better choice.

Comment: Which you could do in Node.js with https://github.com/jpillora/node-edit-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs API is no longer supported use Google Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Please check [Changes to deprecation policies and API spring cleaning](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.mx/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html)