# Updating a published Google spreadsheet with web app?

Tags: python, django, google-sheets

Is it possible (using django and python) to have a web app add content (rows with data) to a spreadsheet that is published?

Comment: Looks like google's documentation is a bit out dated, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019091/google-drive-api-update-spreadsheet-data and https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Answer (score 2):

`gspread` [link](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) is a great Python package to manipulate Google spreadsheets.

The documentation is comprehensive and the package is easy to implement. It allows you to address fields via direct cell name or via the cell coordinates.

```
# With name
val = worksheet.acell('B1').value

# With coords
val = worksheet.cell(1, 2).value
```