# Create spreadsheet using data from local db

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-drive-android-api, android-database

I want to create a spreadsheet using the data stored in the local db. I have 5 columns and data in them. I want to create a spreadsheet having the same columns and data. I have tried using sheets api but I do not understand how to create one taking data from db

This is my code for fetching data from spreadsheet

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {  
String sheetId =  "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        ValueRange response = this.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(sheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values != null) {
            results.add("Name, Major");
            for (List row : values) {
                results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(4));
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

This is my sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit

I did some research and found out that we can edit a spreadsheet using drive api but I am not able to find out how. I have implemented drive api and can create and edit files though
Please help

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019091/google-drive-api-update-spreadsheet-data

Comment: The one which is shown in the above link do not tell how to write . It has sample code for reading only

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Google Sheets API`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), the Google Sheets API v3 (formerly called the Google Spreadsheets API) lets you develop client applications that read and modify worksheets and data in Google Sheets. To fulfill the equivalent functionality of original Sheets+Docs combination, you should use Drive API to perform file manipulations such as search/move/creation/deletion.

In addition to the scopes for Drive API, add the following scope to your grant:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

If you're using [GData client library](https://github.com/google/gdata-java-client) and [Google OAuth client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client), it will be quite easy to setup both services after OAuth 2.0 authorization.

```
// Acquire clientId, clientSecret and refreshToken
...

// Create shared credential
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
.setTransport(transport)
.build().setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

// Setup both servives
Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).build();
SpreadsheetService sheetService = new SpreadsheetService(...);
sheetService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential); // only provided in newer releases
sheetService.useSsl();
```

Resource IDs in both APIs are identical, so you can search id of some file with Drive API methods and access worksheets in the file with Sheets API methods.

```
File file = driveService.files().get().setFields(...).execute();
String feedUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" 
+ file.getId + "/private/full";
WorksheetFeed feed = sheetService.getFeed(feedUrl, WorksheetFeed.class);
```